# C# program stops working after the language setting in control panel is changed (say, from English to German)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a software developed in C#, which is a pure sentefic application. Howver the German users found this software stopped working from time to time, when it is installed on German computers. The temporary solution is to change the Language setting in the control panel, and it works fine after we change the language setting from German to English. This is just a kind of engineering sofware, and the software have nothing relalted to the German or English language. Also, as suggested from other posts in msdn, I have checked the "InitializeComponent()" in the source does several times. There are not strange codes in the "InitializeComponent()" function.

Comment: try to revise your question :)

Comment: What exception do you get? Do you have a kind of log file? Otherwise your are lost...

Comment: You need to show the actual exception the users are getting. Having said this, the reason most likely is that you are trying to parse a string that represents a date or a floating point number without specifying the culture. The result is that it is using the German culture to parse the string which fails when the string is in an English format.

Comment: Does your software do anything with number formats?  Reading them in?  I suspect that if it does anything with number formats that's the issue.

Comment: Is your application copying / moving files?

Comment: All I got is that "***.exe have stopped working." window pop out. No exception window pop out. Also, when I change back to English setting from the Control Panel. The software works fine.

Comment: When do you get the exception? Is it on some user action?

Comment: Are the _German computers_ running on a different operating system?

Comment: My software does some number format. Just get　real time raw data from a usb port (through calling functions, which are provded in a dll file.) After that, this software needs to do some computation works and pops out the realtime results via a C# developed GUI.

There is not copying and moving files during that software.

Comment: The German computer runs on Windows XP, and I guess it is German version. No user's action happened. The software just get a stop working window and frozen there.

Answer (score 2):

When you change locale, you change the meaning of ',' (comma) and '.' (full-stop) when used in numbers. Could it be that you are trying to parse text containing these characters into numbers?

Does your program attempt to initialize numeric fields with formatted numbers, perhaps?

You need to make sure that your code is sensitive to the user's culture when parsing and formatting text. You also need to make sure you use a consistent culture (e.g. the `InvariantCulture`) when reading data stored to file or sent over a network.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET Framework 4.5, you might be interested to read about the [CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> In the .NET Framework 4 and previous versions, by default, the culture
>   of all threads is set to the Windows system culture. For applications
>   whose current culture differs from the default system culture, this
>   behavior is often undesirable.

The examples and their explanations on the page could be quite helpful for your issue.

Also, as a side note, `try{...}catch{...}` blocks are always welcome.

Comment: When develop the programs, I have:
"Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");" and more CultureInfo objects.  Probably, I need to change all of them. Basically, I just know English and this is a software in English. And I assume, everyone know English could use this software.

Comment: Yes. I am using Thread. Also, is there exist a way that the software could work in any/most languages.

Comment: If you don't explicitly set the culture to `en-US` **inside** the thread's start delegate, it will use the system's culture, not your application's.